# CGAL in Eclipse on OSX

Tags: eclipse, macos, cgal

I am trying to use CGAL on OS X 10.7 with Eclipse. I installed CGAL via MacPorts and made Eclipse aware of that by adding /opt/local/include to it's include lists. Now I get linker errors. I am a bit lost here, do you have any suggestions?

This is how I compile:

```
make all 
Building file: ../hit.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -I/opt/local/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"hit.d" -MT"hit.d" -o "hit.o" "../hit.cpp"
Finished building: ../hit.cpp

Building target: Hit
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++  -o "Hit"  ./hit.o   
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "CGAL::assertion_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)", referenced from:
      CGAL::Interval_nt<false>::Interval_nt(double)in hit.o
      CGAL::Interval_nt<false>::Interval_nt(double, double)in hit.o
      bool CGAL::get_certain<bool>(CGAL::Uncertain<bool>)in hit.o
      CGAL::Interval_nt<false>::Test_runtime_rounding_modes::Test_runtime_rounding_modes()in hit.o
      CGAL::Interval_nt<true>::Test_runtime_rounding_modes::Test_runtime_rounding_modes()in hit.o
      CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq(double)in hit.o
      bool CGAL::internal::seg_seg_do_intersect_crossing<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > >(CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> >::Point_2 const&, CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> >::Point_2 const&, CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> >::Point_2 const&, CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> >::Point_2 const&, CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > const&)in hit.o
      ...
  "___gmpq_init", referenced from:
      CGAL::Gmpq_rep::Gmpq_rep()in hit.o
  "___gmpq_clear", referenced from:
      CGAL::Gmpq_rep::~Gmpq_rep()in hit.o
  "boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const*, boost::shared_ptr<boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>, void*, bool)", referenced from:
      boost::thread_specific_ptr<CGAL::Lazy<CGAL::Segment_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > >, CGAL::Segment_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq> >, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>, CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> >, CGAL::NT_converter<CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > > > >::~thread_specific_ptr()in hit.o
      boost::thread_specific_ptr<CGAL::Lazy<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > >, CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq> >, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>, CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> >, CGAL::NT_converter<CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > > > >::~thread_specific_ptr()in hit.o
      boost::thread_specific_ptr<CGAL::Lazy<CGAL::Segment_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > >, CGAL::Segment_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq> >, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>, CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> >, CGAL::NT_converter<CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > > > >::reset(CGAL::Lazy<CGAL::Segment_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > >, CGAL::Segment_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq> >, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>, CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> >, CGAL::NT_converter<CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > > >*)in hit.o
      boost::thread_specific_ptr<CGAL::Lazy<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > >, CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq> >, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>, CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> >, CGAL::NT_converter<CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > > > >::reset(CGAL::Lazy<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > >, CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq> >, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>, CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> >, CGAL::NT_converter<CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > > >*)in hit.o
  "boost::detail::get_tss_data(void const*)", referenced from:
      boost::thread_specific_ptr<CGAL::Lazy<CGAL::Segment_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > >, CGAL::Segment_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq> >, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>, CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> >, CGAL::NT_converter<CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > > > >::get() constin hit.o
      boost::thread_specific_ptr<CGAL::Lazy<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > >, CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq> >, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>, CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> >, CGAL::NT_converter<CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > > > >::get() constin hit.o
  "CGAL::precondition_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)", referenced from:
      CGAL::Handle::Handle(CGAL::Handle const&)in hit.o
      CGAL::Handle::operator=(CGAL::Handle const&)in hit.o
      CGAL::Uncertain<bool>::Uncertain(bool, bool)in hit.o
      CGAL::Uncertain<CGAL::Sign>::Uncertain(CGAL::Sign, CGAL::Sign)in hit.o
  "_mpfr_init2", referenced from:
      CGAL::Real_embeddable_traits<CGAL::Gmpq>::To_interval::operator()(CGAL::Gmpq const&) constin hit.o
  "_mpfr_set_q", referenced from:
      CGAL::Real_embeddable_traits<CGAL::Gmpq>::To_interval::operator()(CGAL::Gmpq const&) constin hit.o
  "_mpfr_get_d", referenced from:
      CGAL::Real_embeddable_traits<CGAL::Gmpq>::To_interval::operator()(CGAL::Gmpq const&) constin hit.o
  "_mpfr_clear", referenced from:
      CGAL::Real_embeddable_traits<CGAL::Gmpq>::To_interval::operator()(CGAL::Gmpq const&) constin hit.o
  "___gmpq_set_d", referenced from:
      CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq(double)in hit.o
  "___gmpq_cmp", referenced from:
      CGAL::Gmpq::operator<(CGAL::Gmpq const&) constin hit.o
  "___gmpq_sub", referenced from:
      CGAL::Gmpq::operator-=(CGAL::Gmpq const&)in hit.o
  "___gmpq_mul", referenced from:
      CGAL::Gmpq::operator*=(CGAL::Gmpq const&)in hit.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Hit] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CGAL uses cmake as building tool and all compiler flags that should be used for a program using CGAL are set up in the file CGALConfig.cmake.

In your case, you are at least missing -lCGAL -lgmp -lmpfr -lboost_thread.

Also look at your CGALConfig.cmake files to check gcc options required (such as frounding-math for example).

Note that cmake can generate makefiles for eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

Although not in Eclipse, this works for me:

```
$ cgal_create_CMakeLists -c Core -s out
$ cmake .
$ make
```

Then to execute the binary:

```
$ ./out
```